# Is there any way to build a GitHub page automatically, when a new issue comes, without third-party server?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

Well, I know this requirement sounds a little bit strange, but we, our team, want to build a website for the issue tracker of the repository.

The basic idea is:

- for every issue, suppose that we have a page connected to the issue;
- on the page, there will be a comment system, which is connected to the issue

  - posting comment on the page will actual become a comment to the issue
  - comments on the issue will be loaded on the page, when the page is opened by browsers.

That is to say, if we have pages connected to issues, respectively, for every specific pair of page and issue, comments on page and issue are equivalent. This is what we have done.

Now, the problem is how to deal with posting new issue. As you could see, the simple system depends on the connection between pages and issues. Hence, in the following situations, a page should be build and set automatically and correctly:

- someone posts a new issue from the GitHub issue tracker;
- someone posts a new issue from the website, and the issue has already been synchronized to the GitHub issue tracker (yes, this is what we have implemented).

We hope that this kind of task could be handled without any third-party server, which means that we do not want to run a new service on any other server host.

Any hints or clues will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you map existing issues to pages?